# Dissecting ruby on rails model, view, controllers and routes for a large project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, hmvc

I want to  separate model view controllers in HMVC form including routes.After reading i found that ruby on rails  does not support HMVC structure.Is there any alternative of doing it?. I also want to separate routes module wise.
Please suggest some best ways of doing it as keeping everything in one place is hard to manage.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what kind of application you are looking for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside your app, with **[Controller Namespaces and Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#controller-namespaces-and-routing)** you can organize in subfolders inside the main MVC structure subsystems of your application. With David's patch to **[Routing](https://gist.github.com/2492118)** you can split up a big `routes.rb` file.

If you prefer to extract "applications" from your main app, and mount them in the router, **[Rails::Engine](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html)** is the way to go.

Answer (score 2):

You can use nested routes: rails guide http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html